# Able to have div encompass part of table?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm making a table of games and times but I want to use javascript to show/hide part of the list. Once 5 games have been listed, all the games following that are to be encompassed within the div that will be showed/hidden by hitting a button. The trouble is, my div does not encompass ANY of the rows of the table, which is weird because the code says otherwise.

Am I not allowed to make a div that encompasses part of a table?

Thanks as always.

```
<table>
<?php
$result = @mysql_query('QUERY REMOVED');
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$count = 0;
    if ($rows == 0) {
        echo '<h3> No games on this day </h3>';
    } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        **a bunch of variable assignments**

        if($count == 5) echo '<tbody class="moreLess">';
        echo '<tr><td><a href="quotes.php?awayid=' . $awayteam_id . '&homeid=' . $hometeam_id . '&date=' . $date . '&time=' . $row['time'] . '&gameid=' . $game_id . '">' . $awayteam . ' @ ' . $hometeam . '</td><td>' . $time . '</td></a></tr>';
        $count++;               
        }
    if($count >= 6) echo '</tbody>'; 
    }
?>
</table>
<div class="moreLessSwitch"><span>More [+]</span></div>
```

In case you wanted it, the javascript I use (tested and working)

```
$(function() {     
           $(".moreLess").hide();

           $(".moreLessSwitch").toggle(function() {             
                $(this).html("<span>Less [-]</span>");            
                $(this).prevAll(".moreLess").slideDown();         
           }, function() {            
                $(this).html("<span>More [+]</span>");            
                $(this).prevAll(".moreLess").slideUp();        
           }); 

        });
```

The table output HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=99iUYq6j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a `div` can't exist between the `table` and `tr` tags.

However, you *can* (and should) use a `tbody` to delineate groups of `tr`.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6wVf/).

**[edit]**

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UgW2/).

Comment: I tried changing my divs to `tbody` tags, it only partially worked. The stuff is properly contained in `moreLess` but won't display when I hit `[+] More`

Comment: what the...? How does that work? Nothing there has a `moreLess` tag, how is the jQuery selecting it?

Comment: I actually got a tweak of your fiddle to work somehow... it won't slide, but will show/hide. Close enough... accepted.

Answer (score 3):

tbody is correct way to define group of rows...

This test code works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".moreLess").hide();

            $(".moreLessSwitch").toggle(function() {             
                $(this).html("<span>Less [-]</span>");            
                $(".moreLess").slideDown();         
            }, function() {            
                $(this).html("<span>More [+]</span>");            
                $(".moreLess").slideUp();        
            }); 
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<?php

$rows = array(array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3),array(1,2,3));

$count = 0;
    if ($rows == 0) {
        echo '<h3> No games on this day </h3>';
    } else {
        while ($row = array_pop($rows)) {

        //**a bunch of variable assignments**

        if($count == 5) echo '<tbody class="moreLess">' . "\r\n";
        echo '<tr><td><a href="quotes.php?awayid=' . $awayteam_id . '&homeid=' . $hometeam_id . '&date=' . $date . '&time=' . $row['time'] . '&gameid=' . $game_id . '">' . $awayteam . ' @ ' . $hometeam . '</td><td>' . $time . '</td></a></tr>' . "\r\n";
        $count++;               
        }
    if($count >= 6) echo "</tbody>\r\n\r\n"; 
    }
?>
</table>
<div class="moreLessSwitch"><span>More [+]</span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the `\r\n` business? I'm not familiar with that markup

Comment: `\r\n` just adds a new line (windows format - @CR@LF) was useful for me to see where the tbody tags were being inserted - not necessary in final implementation

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid.  A `<div>` cannot occur inside a `<table>` unless inside a `<td>` cell, while yours spans several `<tr>` rows.  A better solution would be to assign the `.moreLess` class to the table rows:

```
<tr class='moreLess'>
```

Your jQuery function then slides the table rows in and out of view.

Comment: I updated my code though it still does not work. When I add "row initated" and "row closed"  to the opening and closing tags of `.moreLess`, it shows "row initated" and "row closed" together at the top of the table! huh?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=99iUYq6j

It's a little messy, but you can see my stuff IS being encompassed by the `tbody class="moreLess"`

Comment: @Tory just view source on the page it creates and post it.